# Weighted measures in surveys

Tags: survey, sample

In sample surveys a weight is typically calculated so that the weighted population measure by certain pre-selected categories (e.g., gender, age groups, geographic areas, etc.) match national total that is already known. The question is - are all the other weighted measures (e.g., income, wealth, health insurance coverage, prevalence of certain health conditions, etc.) accurately estimate the national total, which are mostly unknown?